# Lambda trigger again after timeout even sqs visible timeout is same as lambda timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

Lambda has triggered again even after the SQS visibility timeout is the same as lambda timeout around 8min.

Having SQS visibility timeout greater than lambda timeout, inflight messages in sqs were being picked up again in lambdas.

is there a workaround?

we dont have DLQ.

Comment: Your lambda fails to process them. Did you check for any errors?

Comment: Lambda timed out while processing within 8mins and I am expecting sqs time out as well since it has timeout of 8min